# How can a RelativeLayout be used in Android application to move image button to a specific?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-relativelayout

I am creating an Android application that moves an image button randomly on screen. I am confused which layout can help. The absolute layout used to have x and y axis but it's now depreceated. I have tried using relative, but its not working, too. I want to generate random nos to put that into x, y position so that my button keeps on moving.

Here is what I did:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit1);
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);
   machar = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.machar);
    ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.eT1);
    tb=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tb1);
    tb.setOnClickListener(this);
  RelativeLayout r1 =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.l1);

    LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params.leftMargin=10;
    params.rightMargin=20;
    params.topMargin=30;
    params.bottomMargin=40;
    r1.setLayoutParams(params);
    r1.addView(machar);

}
```

Here `machar` is the image button. This code is not working and the XML file contains a relative layout tag named l1 and inside it an image button named machar. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered there is no absolute position in relative layout. You could change you margin right and margin top of machar by random to move your ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that you are trying to add a view that has already been added. The ImageButton machar has already been declared in xml and therefore drawn on the screen when you called `setContentView`.

What i suggest is creating the ImageButton machar programmatically - that is, not declaring it in your xml layout, but instead creating it during your `onCreate` method.

Comment: dose nt help..any other suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

After modify some margin you need to make a call to `requestLayout()`

```
public void requestLayout()
```

Call this when something has changed which has invalidated the layout of this view. This will schedule a layout pass of the view tree.

You must call `requestLayout()` on your View element, and if no `RelativeRule` are `set` over the element, margin will control the position inside the `RelativeLayout`.